# SQL Server 2014 LAST_VALUE in GROUP BY

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, window-functions

Is it possible to use the `LAST_VALUE` keyword within a `GROUP BY` select statement?

```
SELECT colA, 
       LAST_VALUE(colB) 
            OVER (PARTITION BY ... ORDER BY ... ROWS BETWEEN ...) 
FROM MyTable 
GROUP BY colA
```

Comment: please explain your problem better, it's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Make sure you dont fall for this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `window` function can be used in `group by`. May be `sub-select` will do the job

```
select colA,L_values
from
(
SELECT colA, 
       LAST_VALUE(colB) 
            OVER (PARTITION BY ... ORDER BY ... ROWS BETWEEN ...) L_Value
FROM MyTable
) a
group by colA,L_values
```